# Unable to show ads on version oreo or more

Tags: android, admob

I am using Admob, but unable to show ADs in oreo version

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size can only be set once on AdView.

I am using this method in Java file

```
MobileAds.initialize(this,
                getResources().getString(R.string.admob_app_id));

mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_app_id));
```

using this method in xml file

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_id" />
```

This is my app level gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.applist.carstation"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    android {

        configurations.all {

            resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
        }
    }

    allprojects {

        repositories {

            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
            maven {

                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    /*       android support libraries        */
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    /*      noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices       */
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'
}
```

I got this error message when i run my code:

i added ad size but still it is showing this error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size can only be set once on AdView.

Comment: `R.string.admob_app_id` you are finding the same string twice. The errors say exactly what is wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the problem deeply. **The error**:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size can only be set once on AdView.

Look at the line saying: **The ad size can only be set once on AdView.**
And what you have done is also, you set the size to `BANNER` in the XML file and to `AdSize.BANNER` in the Java code. You have set the ad size dual times.

As per what your question asks the simple answer would be to remove either the line specifying Ad size from the Java code or from XML one.

Also, remove the adUnitId from the XML or Java code because this time also these are being called at the same time twice. So, try removing them

Comment: I tried as you tell but i haven't solve this problem

Comment: `mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
@Override
public void onAdClosed() {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad is closed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad failed to load! error code: " + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad left application!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onAdOpened() {
    super.onAdOpened();
   }
  });

  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);`

Comment: when i am using this method then it is call onAdFailedToLoad and error code is 3

Comment: I thing the adUnit id is not working for the ads. also when i go through admob account it is showing app unit id is **not applicable** like : **Banner
0 active
0 enabled
Not applicable**